# Open file manager to a specific location from my app (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, file-manager

I am making an app that downloads a file.  After the file finishes downloading, the user can press a button that will open the file location in their default file manager.

I don't want to use intents as it causes the file manager to act like a file chooser!  I do **NOT** want a file picker.  My app should get lost after the user clicks on the button after showing him the downloaded location.  I will figure out destroying my app later but first I want to fire up the default file manager and point it to the downloaded location.  Let me know how to do this.

I used this code but it acts like a file picker.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); //tried ACTION_VIEW but it says no apps that can perform this action!
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(mDownloadDir); //mDownloadDir is file object
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder");
        mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
```

Comment: Just try with mContext.startActivity(intent). For your activity to finish call ... finish();

Comment: `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Just remove that as that is the cause of the trouble.

Comment: Android does not have a file manager, let alone a default one.

Comment: Tried without Intent.ACTION* - I have 2 file managers on the test system - one crashes and the other opens at another default location.

Comment: Amaze file manager - it opens but to a generic location.
CyanogenMod file manager - it crashes.

When i don't pass any Intent.ACTION* when creating new Intent object.

`Intent intent = new Intent();`